# nginx redirect not correct

Tags: nginx, mongrel

I'm using nginx as the front end of my mongrel. And mongrel is listening on 3001, and nginx is listening on 3000.

In my application, there will be a redirection after creating a model. let's say, I post a request to http://**xxxx:3000**/users, it should be redirect to http://**xxxx:3000**/users/1, (1 is the id of the new user), but actually, it was redirected to http://**xxxx**/users/1, which cause a 404 error.

Why the port 3000 is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using `proxy_pass` ? You should add this line:
`proxy_set_header   Host    $host:3000;`

You need put your nginx config up here.

====

better solution:

`proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`

`$host` not include port, and `$http_host` is the value from http header, it is added by browser.